# Mysql syntax error during an update but code look fine

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have a strange issue with a Mysql Update and I'm not sure what is causing it. I suspect something is wrong with the table itself but the field causing the error appears to be defined the same as other fields in the table. I can recreate the error in phpMyAdmin on the SQL tab and also in php code. I am completely stumped. 
The fields in the table are defined as follows:

```
bnumber is INT length=11
bname is VARCHAR length=60 Collation=latin1_swedish_ci
twittername is VARCHAR length=15 Collation=latin1_swedish_ci
desc is VARCHAR length=60 Collation=latin1_swedish_ci
```

This update statement works:

```
update tbl1 set bname='myName', twittername='myTweet' where bnumber=1;
```

this one gives me the error:

```
update tbl1 set bname='myName', twittername='myTweet', desc='test' where bnumber=1;
```

the error I get is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc='Main' where bnumber=1' at line 1.
```

I don't seem to have any issues selecting from the table or inserting to the table. Only update is giving me the error.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Try with backticks around `desc`, you know `desc` is a keyword and synonym for `describe`, right?

Comment: desc is a reserved word.  you need to escape it.

Comment: @injekt: Is it not synonym for DESCENDING too?

Comment: @Mr47 Ah yeah, that too! Reserved either way :D

Comment: Hi, no I didn't know desc was a key word. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`desc` is a reserved word in MySQL.  You must quote it in backticks.

Comment: Hi, no I didn't know desc was a key word. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`desc` is a keyword. Escape it with backticks.

```
update tbl1 
    set bname='myName', 
        twittername='myTweet', 
        `desc`='test' 
    where bnumber=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

desc is a reserved word in mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Updated your sql as below and it will work fine;

```
update tbl1 set bname='myName', twittername='myTweet', `desc`='test'
where bnumber=1;
```

Comment: You can use DESC as a field name, it just needs to be escaped when used.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use `desc` as a field name.
change fieldname to desc1 and try.

desc is for  `oder by name desc`

Comment: You can use DESC as a field name, it just needs to be escaped when used.